# Unknown error on if, else if, else statement

Tags: java, eclipse, jcreator

I keep getting a syntax error on my last else statement in a string of if, else if , else , and I can't figure out why nor can I find anywhere that tells me what's really confusing is I have done this type of if else statement setup before and never had this problem. I have tried using 2 coding programs (JCreator and Eclipse) but they both give me an error Eclipse gives me a syntax error on the word else and JCreator on the entire statement saying it has no if statement to pair with it, but I have done one like this and didn't need an if statement as is was the final one.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Hotel 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String answer = "";
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            GuestInterface go = new GuestInterface();
            PassswordField hotel = new PassswordField();

            System.out.println("do you wish do acces the guest interface or the hotel staff interface? ");
            System.out.println("Hint: hotel staff -or- guest");
            answer = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("hotel Staff"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter username");
                answer = keyboard.nextLine();
                hotel.readPassword("Enter Passsword \n ");
                System.out.print("\n" + "incorect Password");
                System.out.println("System will now shut down");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Guest"))
            {
                go.run();
            }
            else //error throws on this statment
            {
                System.out.println("uncompatible responce");
                System.out.println("System ato shut down activated");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `else without if` you have a semicolon at the end of `if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Guest"));`

Comment: What is error message, you failed to mention.

Comment: Hint: `bolean` doesn't get syntax-highlighted in your post for a reason.

Comment: the error message that im being given is rather non descript in eclipse I'm given the message that the token is improper syntax and need deleted and in jcreator it that i have no if statement paired with the else

Comment: as for the misplaced semi colon that was a mess up by me while typing this into the question its not actually part of the code

Comment: Voting to close as questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error.

Comment: There are no syntax errors AFAIK in the twice updated code sample. Please reformulate this as a new question showing exactly the error you got, and please copy and paste the code into SO so that simple typos don't cause readers problems (44 people have read this question so far).

Comment: I updated it twice because I typed it wrong twice, once in the code and once in the question, it now matches what I have in my program and the errors that i say i am getting in the question are what i am still getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a `;` at the end of this line:

```
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Guest"));
```

So that is a seperate if-statement. Right after that, you start with this:

```
        {
            go.run();
        }
        else //error throws on this statment
        {
            // (...)
        }
```

Which makes no sense to the compiler, **because it didn't start with an if-statement**.
Remove the `;` to solve the error.

Comment: ya i know that was an accident while typing the code into this thing its not actually in the program just got there when i hit a wrong key and didn't realise it.

Comment: So do you still have an error now? If not, please accept my answer to indicate the question is solved.

Comment: yes I do but I don't mean to give you the impression that your answer was not helpful as I didn't know that that would cause an error to occur and I thank you for that, but yes I am still getting the same error as before